# Loading .Net Fx query

Tags: .net

I have built a simple C#.Net app on a M/C with only .Net FX 1.1 present. Now when I execute this app on a M/C where there is :
   Case 1) Only .Net fx 2.0 is installed
   Case 2) Both .Net Fx 1.1 amd 2.0 are installed

How is it determined to load the appropriate .Net framework in the above cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior as I understand it is your 1.1. app will use the 1.1 Framework unless it's unavailable, in which case it will use the 2.0 Framework, this is how an application can be compiled against the 1.1 Framework but can often still work on Vista, where only the 2.0 framework is available.

Some handy resources I've used in the past when looking at these issues are Thomas F. Abraham's posts [here](http://blogs.digineer.com/blogs/tabraham/archive/2005/12/09/15.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.digineer.com/blogs/tabraham/archive/2006/12/18/net-framework-1-1-and-2-0-and-3-0-side-by-side-sxs.aspx), this guide on [installing the .Net Framework 1.1 on Vista](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/12/27/install-microsoft-net-framework-11-on-windows-vista-fix-regsvcsexe-fails-error/) (if you have to support some legacy application's that require it) and this post which documents running [asp.net 1.1 and 2.0](http://www.gafvert.info/iis/article/install_asp_net_20_side_by_side.htm) side by side (which describes the application pool issues you will encounter if attempting to mix the framework version of applications).